# Evenly distribute points on a circle

Tags: javascript, geometry, trigonometry

I need to distribute points evenly on a circumference of a circle, and I'm out of my wits. The result is not exactly circular but rather spiraly, especially with larger numbers of points. I've researched it vigorously but still can't figure out where I could make a mistake.

```js
  window.onload = function() {
      var num = 15;

      var angle = (2 * Math.PI)/(num+1); var count = 0;
      var demo = document.getElementById("demo"); 

      function Dot() {
          this.angle = angle * count;
          count++;
          this.x = Math.cos(this.angle) * 200; 
          this.y = Math.sin(this.angle) * 200;
      }

      Dot.prototype.create = function() {
          var dot = document.createElement("div");
          dot.style.top = this.y + 100 + "px";
          dot.style.left = this.x + 200 + "px";
          dot.className = "dot";
          demo.appendChild(dot);
      }

      for (var i = 0; i < num; i++) {
          var d = new Dot();
          d.create(); 
      }
  }
```

```css
  .dot {
      height: 20px;
      width: 20px;
      border-radius: 50%;
      background: blue;
      position: relative;
      text-align: center;
  }
```

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
      <title>Metcalfe's Law Demo</title>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
      <script type="text/javascript" src="code.js"></script>
    </head>
        <body>
            <div id="container">
                <div id="demo">
                </div>
            </div>
        </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The main mistake is bloody simple - just change the style `position: relative` to `position: absolute`:

```js
window.onload = function() {
      var num = 12;

      var angle = (2 * Math.PI)/(num); var count = 0;
      var demo = document.getElementById("demo"); 
      console.log(angle)

      function Dot() {
          this.angle = angle * count;
          count++;
          console.log(this.angle,count)
          this.x = Math.cos(this.angle) * 200; 
          this.y = Math.sin(this.angle) * 200;
      }

      Dot.prototype.create = function() {
          var dot = document.createElement("div");
          dot.style.top = this.y + 200 + "px";
          dot.style.left = this.x + 200 + "px";
          dot.className = "dot";
          demo.appendChild(dot);
      }

      for (var i = 0; i < num; i++) {
          var d = new Dot();
          d.create(); 
      }
  }
```

```css
.dot {
      height: 20px;
      width: 20px;
      border-radius: 50%;
      background: blue;
      position: absolute;
      text-align: center;
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
      <title>Metcalfe's Law Demo</title>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
      <script type="text/javascript" src="code.js"></script>
    </head>
        <body>
            <div id="container">
                <div id="demo">
                </div>
            </div>
        </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Thank you, it works now. I didn't look for the problem in the styles, which was stupid. Your other corrections are also on point.